# Add Sidebar Menu in Other Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

1. **Sidebar Menu add in other activity but App crash and given error**

   **How to Add Sidebar Menu in Every Activity**

   ** Siderbar Code **

   package com.example.bulksms;

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;


   import com.example.bulksms.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
   import com.example.bulksms.model.NavDrawerItem;

   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.app.Fragment;
   import android.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.content.res.Configuration;
   import android.content.res.TypedArray;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import com.example.bulksms.R;

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public class Home extends ActionBarActivity  {

       protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
       protected ListView mDrawerList;
       protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

       // nav drawer title
       private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

       // used to store app title
       private CharSequence mTitle;

       // slide menu items
       protected String[] navMenuTitles;
       private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

       private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
       private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

           //if TheradPolicy When app crash automatically.
           //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

           mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

           // load slide menu items
           navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

           // nav drawer icons from resources
           navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

           mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

           navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

           // adding nav drawer items to array
           // Home
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
           // Find People
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
           // Photos
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
           // Communities, Will add a counter here
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
           // Pages
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
           // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
           navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


           // Recycle the typed array
           navMenuIcons.recycle();

           mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

           // setting the nav drawer list adapter
           adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
           mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

           // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

           mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                   R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                   R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                   R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
           ) {
               public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                   // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                   invalidateOptionsMenu();
               }

               public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                   // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                   invalidateOptionsMenu();
               }
           };
           mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

           if (savedInstanceState == null) {
               // on first time display view for first nav item
               displayView(0);
           }
       }

       /**
        * Slide menu item click listener
        * */
       private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
               ListView.OnItemClickListener {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                   long id) {
               // display view for selected nav drawer item
               displayView(position);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
           if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
               return true;
           }
           // Handle action bar actions click
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.action_settings:
               return true;
           default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
           }
       }

       /* *
        * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
        */
       @Override
       public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
           boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
           menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
           return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

       /**
        * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
        * */
       @SuppressLint("NewApi")
       protected void displayView(int position) {
           // update the main content by replacing fragments
           Fragment fragment = null;
           switch (position) {
           case 0:
               fragment = new HomeFragment();
               break;
           case 1:
               fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
               break;
           case 2:
               fragment = new PhotosFragment();
               break;
           case 3:
               fragment = new CommunityFragment();
               break;
           case 4:
               fragment = new PagesFragment();
               break;
           case 5:
               fragment = new LogoutFragment();
               break;

           default:
               break;
           }

           if (fragment != null) {
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
               fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

               // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
               mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
               mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
               setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
               mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
           } else {
               // error in creating fragment
               Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
           }
       }

       public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
           mTitle = title;
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
       }

       /**
        * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
        * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
        */

       @Override
       protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
           mDrawerToggle.syncState();
       }

       @Override
       public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
           super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
           // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
           mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       }

   }
   ```

### **Other Activity Code**

```
enter code here
package com.example.bulksms;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Sendsms extends Home {

    String id;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    public Typeface font;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sendsms);

        // FontAwesome Icon 
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        //
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Button select=(Button) findViewById(R.id.send_bulk_sms);
        Button logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setTypeface(font);
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                select();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    }

    /**
     * Function: Select Phone Number To Send Sms.
     * using Http Request.
     * Get the Response and calling The SmsSend functions.
     */

    public void select() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ayattechnologies.com/demo/sentsms/getNumber.php?Getdata=true");
            //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            //
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }     

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

        JSONObject obj_resultParent  = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray obj_resultarray    = new JSONArray();

         //       
    try
        {

        JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(result); //Json Get From Server
        // create apps list

        for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) 
            {    

                JSONObject json         = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                //
                String senderNumber     = json.getString("phoneNumber");
                String subject          = json.getString("subject");
                String message          = json.getString("message");
                String Id               = json.getString("id");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SenderNumber : "+senderNumber+"Messages: "+message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //
                boolean smsresult = sendSMS(senderNumber,subject, message);
                if(smsresult)
                {
                    JSONObject json_resultget = new JSONObject();

                    json_resultget.put("Id", Id); // Set the first name/pair
                    json_resultget.put("status",smsresult);
                    obj_resultarray.put(json_resultget);
                } //
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }

            obj_resultParent.put("smsresults", obj_resultarray);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SenderNumber : "+obj_resultParent.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ayattechnologies.com/demo/sentsms/getNumber.php?Postdata=true");

              try {
                // Add your data
                  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsresults",obj_resultParent.toString()));
                  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SenderNumber : "+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              }
            //
    }

    /** 
     * Function: SendSms function send sms 
     * @param: SenderNumberTo String  use for sender number
     * @param:Subject. 
     * @param:Message.
     * */
    public    boolean sendSMS(String senderNumberto,String subject, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(senderNumberto, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending SMS failed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }


    }



}
```

### **Error Code Here **

12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): Process: com.example.bulksms, PID: 13472
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bulksms/com.example.bulksms.Sendsms}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.example.bulksms.Sendsms.onCreate(Sendsms.java:63)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
    12-31 13:04:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    ... 11 more

```
**After remove Inflator  only extends class **
```

**Error **

```
12-31 15:06:13.951: E/(29235): appName=com.example.bulksms, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-31 15:06:13.951: E/(29235): 0
12-31 15:06:13.951: E/(29235): appName=com.example.bulksms, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-31 15:06:13.951: E/(29235): 0
12-31 15:06:17.024: E/FragmentManager(29235): No view found for id 0x7f090056 (com.example.bulksms:id/frame_container) for fragment HomeFragment{4237a568 #0 id=0x7f090056}
12-31 15:06:17.024: E/FragmentManager(29235): Activity state:
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):   Local FragmentActivity 4236f7a8 State:
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     mCreated=falsemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     mLoadersStarted=false
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):   FragmentManager misc state:
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@4236fa48
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@4236fa48
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     mCurState=1 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):   View Hierarchy:
12-31 15:06:17.027: E/FragmentManager(29235):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42370770 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.028: E/FragmentManager(29235):       android.widget.LinearLayout{42370ea8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.028: E/FragmentManager(29235):         android.view.ViewStub{42371950 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313}
12-31 15:06:17.028: E/FragmentManager(29235):         android.widget.FrameLayout{42371bf8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.028: E/FragmentManager(29235):           android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{42373630 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09003c app:id/decor_content_parent}
12-31 15:06:17.029: E/FragmentManager(29235):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout{42373d90 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
12-31 15:06:17.029: E/FragmentManager(29235):               
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235): android.widget.ScrollView{4237a950 VFED.V.. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09004d app:id/scrollView1}
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{4237b640 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235):                   android.widget.LinearLayout{4237ba08 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4237be20 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.widget.LinearLayout{4237c438 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.030: E/FragmentManager(29235):                   android.widget.LinearLayout{4237c798 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.031: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.widget.ImageView{4237cf30 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.031: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4237d2a0 VFED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09004f app:id/tvInvisibleError}
12-31 15:06:17.031: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.widget.LinearLayout{4237d818 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.031: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{4237db78 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090065 app:id/send_bulk_sms}
12-31 15:06:17.031: E/FragmentManager(29235):                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{4237e328 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090066 app:id/logout}
12-31 15:06:17.032: E/FragmentManager(29235):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{42374258 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09003d app:id/action_bar_container}
12-31 15:06:17.032: E/FragmentManager(29235):               android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{42374820 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09003e app:id/action_bar}
12-31 15:06:17.033: E/FragmentManager(29235):                 android.widget.TextView{423773f0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.033: E/FragmentManager(29235):                 android.widget.ImageButton{42374fd0 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0}
12-31 15:06:17.033: E/FragmentManager(29235):               android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{42376050 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09003f app:id/action_context_bar}
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235): Process: com.example.bulksms, PID: 29235
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bulksms/com.example.bulksms.Sendsms}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090056 (com.example.bulksms:id/frame_container) for fragment HomeFragment{4237a568 #0 id=0x7f090056}
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090056 (com.example.bulksms:id/frame_container) for fragment HomeFragment{4237a568 #0 id=0x7f090056}
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5352)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
12-31 15:06:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(29235):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line number `63` in `Sendsms ` ?

Comment: Button logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

Comment: are you sure that this `logout` is declared on the right activity, maybe you have it the other layout

Comment: yes its right declear

Comment: i have remove above code but not working beacuse i want to add sidebar in all activites but its given error